# Are boost mapped files RAII?

Tags: c++, boost, memory-mapped-files

From what I can tell from documentation they aren't, on the other hand RAII is the one of the features of modern cpp.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html

EDIT: It turns out that the answer is yes, but please please dont forget to use .is_open().

Comment: [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/libs/interprocess/)' memory mapped files are **definitely** RAII; no idea about Boost.IOStreams though. :-[

Comment: Sadly, the documentation on section [*§3.7 Object Lifetimes*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/lifetimes.html) has only this to say: "[To be supplied in the next release]" :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the implementation, the mapped_source/mapped_sink both contain a shared pointer to the underlying mapped_file_impl [(See here for the mapped_file_impl source)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/src/mapped_file.cpp)

As you can see, once the last reference is destroyed, it calls the destructor which detaches from the mapped file.  However, it does not destroy the mapped file, no more than destroying an `ofstream` deletes the underlying file.

Comment: Tnx, btw do you know if they are thread safe in a sense that multiple threads can write to differenf files at the same time?

Comment: Different Devices appear to be thread safe, as they each do their own mapping/buffers.   Multiple threads writing to the same device, I'm not sure.